# Elastic filter with dot (.) in name

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I'm pretty new to ELK and seem to start with the complicated questions ;-)
I have elements that look like following:

```
{
    "_index": "asd01",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "...",
    "_score": 0,
    "_source": {
      "@version": "1",
      "my-key": "hello.world.to.everyone",
      "@timestamp": "2018-02-05T13:45:00.000Z",
      "msg": "myval1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "asd01",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "...",
    "_score": 0,
    "_source": {
      "@version": "1",
      "my-key": "helloworld.from.someone",
      "@timestamp": "2018-02-05T13:44:59.000Z",
      "msg": "myval2"
    }
```

I want to filter for my-key(s) that start with "hello." and want to ignore elements that start with "helloworld.". The dot seem to be interpreted as a wildchard and every kind of escaping doesn't seem to work.

With a filter for that as I want to be able to use the same expression in Kibana as well as in the API directly.

Can someone point me to how to get it working with Elasticsearch 6.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not being used as a wildcard, it's just being removed by the default analyzer (standard analyzer). If you do not specify a mapping, elasticsearch will create one for you. For string fields it will create a multi value field, the default will be text (with default analyzer - standard) and keyword field with the keyword analyzer. If you do not want this behaviour you must specify the mapping explicitly during index creation, or update it and reindex the data

Try using this

```
GET asd01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "my-key.keyword": {
        "value": "hello.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!

Comment: If it helped then you can accept the answer as well